# Using properties pass into a component

Tags: react-native

I have a component that is used to draw out player profiles, and I need to pass in one of two variables; men or ladies.

This is done simply by importing the component and calling;

```
<PlayerProfiles typeOfProfile='Men'/>
```

The component it is calling, is setup as so;

```
const PlayerProfiles = (typeOfProfile) => {
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

function playertype(val) {
    return 'https://s2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx.json';;
}

useEffect(() => {
fetch(playertype(typeOfProfile))
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    setData(json)
    })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);

return (
<View style={styles.body}>
  <View style={styles.topscroll}>
  {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
    <FlatList
      data={data.filter(data => data.Sex == 'Men')}
```

The challenge I'm having is that when want to use the typeOfProfile value instead of the hardcoded 'Men' in `data={data.filter(data => data.Sex == typeOfProfile)}` it's not reading the value as a string.

I have tried using JSON.stringify(typeOfProfile) but that returns the name of the property (typeOfProfile) as well. Before I strip back all the non-value parts, my question is what is the simplest way to get the value passed to typeOfProfile?

Comment: The plural of "man" is "men" - not "mens" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `typeOfProfile` prop is not used correctly.

```js
const PlayerProfiles = (props) => {
  const typeOfProfile = props.typeOfProfile;
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

or you can restructure the props

```js
const PlayerProfiles = ({ typeOfProfile }) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

See [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: Thanks @strdr4605, I'm new to react native (literally 2 weeks), so still missing out some of the basics...